# JS try / catch generating jshint errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any suggestion as to why the following implementation works, but is considered a jshint error?

```
try {
    map.childNodes.length;
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

I just want to see if childNodes has a length before iterating.

Similar thing here:

```
try {
    response.errors.length > 0;
    deferred.reject(response);
} catch (e) {
    deferred.resolve(response);
}
```

Comment: Huh? Why would you do that? Use an `if`.  In particular, that will only fail if the array is `null`, not if it's empty.

Comment: console.log will generate an error in IE.  Don't use exceptions for flow control.

Comment: don't worry about the console log, that was just for this example. but you're right.

Comment: @Deadron I agree with the point of flow control but it's slightly inaccurate that IE will generate an error. If the developers console is open it actually won't. which indeed is somewhat odd!

Comment: JSHint does tell you what the "error" is doesn't it? Either way that first block doesn't do quite what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning from JSHint is:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

The warning shows up even without the use of a `try..catch`. JSHint is letting you know that `map.childNodes.length;` as a standalone statement probably isn't useful, and is likely indicative of a coding mistake; i.e., in most cases, you want to *do* something with the value, not just access it as a standalone statement. For example, you get the same warning with the (useless) statement `5;`.

Of course, *sometimes* it might be useful to access a property as the only behavior in a statement. For example, if you have a getter function defined on the property with `Object.defineProperty`, then accessing the property will trigger the getter function. However, it's vastly more likely that a value-only statement is coding error, so JSHint warns you about the suspicious code.

That said, your approach could be improved, assuming you're worried that `response.error` might be a falsey value (`undefined`, `null`) instead of an object:

```
if(response.errors && response.errors.length > 0) {
    deferred.resolve(response);
} else {
    deferred.reject(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're abusing conditional operators that ought to be in `if` conditions. JSHint isn't meant to be approving of anything you *can* do in Javascript.

For the first, you could use an Array type check, such as:

```
if (toString.call(map.childNodes) === '[object Array]') {
  //iterator
}
```

For the second, something like this perhaps:

```
if (response.errors && response.errors.length > 0) {
  deferred.reject(response);
} else {
  deferred.resolve(response);
}
```

Comment: The _.length_ property won't be an array. You'd need to test _.childNodes_, which also may be some sort of non-array collection. The same style test as the second block is fine...

Comment: In the first block, there was no concern about length being greater than 0, just that the property was there, it seemed what was really intended was to validate it was an array.